# Bonding Ground Rod for Rooftop Antenna

Tags: electrical, tv-antenna, grounding-and-bonding

I am installing a rooftop antenna on the end of my house, opposite the end where the ground rod is located.

I plan to install a new 8' ground rod on the ground directly under the antenna. I need to connect (bond) the new ground rod to the old ground rod. I plan to do this with 6 AWG copper wire. Because of a variety of obstacles, running the 6 AWG around my house to the existing ground rod would be difficult.

Would it be safe to run the 6 AWG bonding jumper in PVC conduit through my semi-finished basement? For example, attached to an unfinished concrete wall?

Edit: I've ended up running the 6 AWG in the ground around my house. I could not find any good information about running it inside versus outside, so Iopted for the safe route, to keep it outside.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to connect the old ground rod and the new?

Comment: It is required by code. Here is one short explanation I found: "Not grounding to the house electrical system leads to a difference in potential between two grounds." Also it can cause ground loops.

Comment: NEC 810.21(J) says "(J) Bonding of Electrodes. A bonding jumper not smaller than 6 AWG copper or equivalent shall be connected between the radio and television equipment grounding electrode and the power grounding electrode system at the building or structure served where separate electrodes are used."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've cleaned up after lightning hits an antenna, and designed spark gaps to protect electronics.  The last thing I'd do is install a lightning rod through my basement.  That stuff should stay outside, irrespective of NEC 810.21(J).  Ground loops are not a serious concern in this particular application.

I'd also consider changing the 8' rod into two 4' rods, which are far easier and safer to drive into the ground.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where I am you must use 8-10 foot ground rods. The rod must hit wet soil, which is why 4 foot rods are no longer allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

PVC or EMT conduit can be used to route the wire.  If you're just passing it through a basement, insulated wire can be passed directly with the conduit being utilized where the wire is not protected by the home.

Comment: It was my understanding that I could run it right through the basement, I just wanted to verify. I already have bare copper connected to the gas pipes, water pipes and service entrance.